# npm not installing any module

Tags: node.js, npm, node.js-connect

I am new to node.js.
I have installed node.js and I tested the installation is ok. `node -v` and `npm -v` command are showing the version numbers.
But when I install any module it's not working.
For example when I try to install the connect module using npm install connect, it's showing following result.

```
C:\>npm install connect

connect@3.3.5 node_modules\connect

├── utils-merge@1.0.0

├── parseurl@1.3.0

├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)

└── finalhandler@0.3.4 (escape-html@1.0.1, on-finished@2.2.0)

C:\>
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Can you check your node_modules folder. I think it did install.

Comment: So it looks like it is installed correctly. You might, however, consider using a separate directory for your project instead of `c:/`.

Answer (score 0):

That installed it. However it installed it "locally" (to the current folder) and not globally. If you want to install it globally then use `-g`.

`npm install -g connect`